# How to add header columns based on data fetch from the database in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server-2012

I have a `GridView` and want to make headers dynamically based on the some SQL query like...

```
select question from quiz where quizid is 123.
```

This query will return `*` number of questions based on the `quizid`.

How to create headers with the data that's been selected from database?

Comment: Are you asking, how to add column headers based on a query that is unique for that purpose and does not affect the main data source of the overall GridView? If yes, then that's my problem as well. Creating a datatable and binding it to the gridview wipes the data that was originally retrieved from the main data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DataTable` to help with this.

I don't know which technologies you used for database management, but I used `LinQ to SQL`. And the following is my sample:

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

protected DataTable GetDataSource() 
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    var questions = db.ExecuteQuery<string>("select question from quiz where quizid is 123").ToList();

    // Header implementation
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var question in questions)
    {
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(question);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        count++;
    }

    // Rows implementation here
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    ...
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    return dt;
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = GetDataSource();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: hi... can you please elaborate the same for simple mssql server... i dont have info abount linq

Comment: About linq, you can learn from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384470.aspx

Comment: To fill rows, you have to make new query like "questions" variable definition and then loop for bind data and add DataRows to DataTable. If you want soe sample please give me the related database table structure.

Comment: can i have ur mail id , i will mail you the table structure!!! mine one is garg.abhisar@gmail.com

Comment: Yes, I sent you my email address :)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to Add `HeaderText` Dynamically on `RowDataBound` event.
You could try something like

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       GridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "New Header text for First Column";
    }
}
```

You could find `RowDataBound` on properties >> Events of `GridView` control. and [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) fires on binding of every row of `GridView`.